# Where to find pre-trained models for transfer learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, transfer-learning

I am new to the machine learning field, but I wanted to try and implement a simple classification algorithm with Keras. Unfortunately, I have a very small set of data, so I thought to try to apply transfer learning to the problem; however, I couldn't find anything on this online, so I wanted to understand which are the best places to look for a pre-trained neural network. Do you have any suggestion in this regard? Which website is best for getting an idea on how to start a machine learning project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keras itself provides some of the successful image processing neural networks pretrained on the ImageNet: https://keras.io/applications/

Other deep learning libraries also offer some pretrained models, notably:

- TensorFlow: https://github.com/tensorflow/models
- caffe: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo
- caffe2: https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/wiki/Model-Zoo
- pytorch: https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch
- Lasagne: https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes

Many pretrained models for various platforms can also be found at https://www.gradientzoo.com.

Moreover, if you are interested in some particular network architecture, authors sometimes provide pretrained models themselves, e.g. [ResNeXt](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ResNeXt).

Answer (score 6):

Since the question title is generic (and not specific to computer vision), I will give the **NLP**-related answer as well, in case it helps someone who stumbles upon looking for pretrained vector embeddings:

The two most popular pre-trained vector embeddings can be found on these links:

- GloVe- https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/
- Tensorflow Embeddings - https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/

There are also a couple of less popular and/or more recent ones:

- LexVec - https://github.com/alexandres/lexvec
- FastText - https://github.com/icoxfog417/fastTextJapaneseTutorial
- Meta-Embeddings - http://cistern.cis.lmu.de/meta-emb/

Comment: Do you think I should edit the title? Also, I am actually looking for a pre-trained texture classification model, but reckoning such a question to be too specific, I thought a general idea on where people look for pre-trained models would have been a good starting point

Comment: As it stands, it is a general question, so assuming there aren't others like this on the website, this may be a useful source for everyone. However, I don't think someone with the answer to the specific question you have in mind will be drawn to this just from the title.